# What does あらいだす mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does あらいだす mean? I have been hearing it from my colleague and based on his explanation it means to identify. For example identify the problem. I tried to search the net and it only results to "Washout" 洗い出して{あらいだして}. Does anyone know what this mean? if it really is identify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to jisho.org [洗い出す](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E3%81%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0%E3%81%99&eng=&dict=edict) means "to reveal by investigation". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

From EDICT via Rikaichan:

> 洗い出す あらいだす (< -te)
>   洗いだす あらいだす (< -te)
>   (v5s,vt) to reveal something by washing the surface; to bring to light; to reveal by investigation